# Upload all productFlavors with crashlytics

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My problem is simple but I don't find the solution. In my app, I have added crashlytics and I want to use `beta` to upload builds.
For one productFlavor I use the task called `crashlyticsUploadDistribution<ProductFlavor>Release` and before I have to assemble build with `assemble<ProductFlavor>Release` otherwise it can upload a wrong apk.

Now I want to merge this two tasks in only one so in my gradle.file

```
task prepareFabric(group: 'aat') {
    println 'HereSTART'
    dependsOn 'assemble<ProductFlavor>Release'
}

task publishRealeaseOnFabric(group: 'aat') {
    mustRunAfter prepareFabric
    println 'HereFINAL'
    dependsOn 'crashlyticsUploadDistribution<ProductFlavor>Release'
}
```

Now when I execute my task (`publishRealeaseOnFabric`), `print` appears but the following line is not executed
`dependsOn 'assemble<ProductFlavor>Release'`

My question is : How can I make two tasks `assemble<ProductFlavor>Release` and then `crashlyticsUploadDistribution<ProductFlavor>Release` in one task ?

Answer (score 0):

I use that it create all the flavors

```
//Creates the app for all the productFlavors
File crashlyticsProperties = new File("${project.projectDir.absolutePath}/fabric.properties")
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
        println("flavor : " + variant.name)
        def variantSuffix = variant.name.capitalize()
        def generatePropertiesTask = task("fabricGenerateProperties${variantSuffix}") << {
            Properties properties = new Properties()
            properties.put("apiKey", flavor.fabricApiKey)
            properties.put("apiSecret", flavor.fabricApiSecret)
            properties.store(new FileWriter(crashlyticsProperties), "")
        }

        def generateResourcesTask = project.tasks.getByName("fabricGenerateResources${variantSuffix}")
        generateResourcesTask.dependsOn generatePropertiesTask
        generateResourcesTask.doLast {
            println "Removing fabric.properties"
            crashlyticsProperties.delete()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it upload to fabric ? I don't see any mention to `crashlyticsUploadDistribution<ProductFlavor>Release`